# Difference between creating a folder and creating a project in CRXDE Lite in CQ5

Tags: aem

I am using CQ5 and trying to create my first component and template. While creating a component/template in apps folder we always create a folder and not a project.

I want to know what is a difference between a folder and a project.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is creating a folder just creates a folder, whereas creating a project creates a sample working project.

When you use `Create Folder ...` option in `CRXDE`, it tries to create a folder under the selected path in the repository. You need to use this option multiple times to create the required project structure, as well as create the appropriate components, templates, bundles, content and packages accordingly.

Whereas, you use the `Create Project ...` option in `CRXDE`, regardless of the current path you are in, it creates the following

1. `/apps/<<project-name>>` - The project container
2. `/apps/<<project-name>>/components` - The components folder for your project, containing a sample component.
3. `/apps/<<project-name>>/src` - The src folder, containing a sample bundle source code.
4. `/apps/<<project-name>>/install` - The install folder, containing the built bundle
5. `/content/<<project-name>>` - The content node, which `sling:resourceType` pointing to the sample component in your project.
6. `/etc/packages/<<java-suffix>>/<<project-name>>.zip` - The package for your project, with the filters `/apps/<<project-name>>` and `/content/<<project-name>>`

Like mentioned before, it would be a working sample. Hence accessing `http://<<server-host>>:<<port>>/content/<<project-name>>.html`, would actually display the text

> Hello World

The [Adobe documentation for Developing with CRXDE Lite](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/core/developing/development_tools/developing_with_crxde_lite.html#Creating%20a%20Project) itself is self explanatory.